# Как оптимально решить проблему с кодировкой русского языка в excel через код на python

Tags: python, парсер, excel, кодировка, utf-8

Доброго времени суток!

Возник такой вопрос: как через код на python задать настройки для заполнения таблицы в Excel таким образом, чтобы выполняя программу с любого компьютера, русские символы всегда кодировались верно, а не в виде непонятных иероглифов. **Как сделать так**, чтобы у заказчика, который со своего компьютера будет запускать код, русские символы отображались верно, не смотря на какие-либо индивидуальные настройки кодировки в Excel или Операционной Системы (будьте добры, в объяснении сделать на этом акцент).

Я решаю следующую задачу: заполняю таблицу Excel информацией, собранной парсером. Среди материалов, которые записываются в таблицу, есть русские слова, которые в файле excel изображаются как иероглифы.
В коде при создании файла указала кодировку "utf-8", пробовала также с кодировкой 'Windows-1251'- не помогло.

```
with open('table.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8', newline='') as file:
```

(красным цветом на изображении выделены примеры неправильно кодируемых слов(которые должны быть на русском)
[image]

Если что-то в моем вопросе непонятно, то пишите, обязательно дополню. А так, буду рада любой помощи. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: попробуйте при сохранении csv файла указать кодировку `encoding='utf-8-sig'`.

Comment: Мне кажется проблема у вас возникает до сохранения в Excel. Попробуйте записать результат Парсинга в текстовый файл с utf-8 кодировкой и посмотреть что получиться

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Поменяла кодировку, и все заработало!

Comment: Мария, опишите как решили проблему в ответе, что бы другие участники могли воспользоваться готовым рецептом.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло следующее:

```
with open('table.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
```

еще может помочь так же указание delimiter=';' для записи через ; т.к win exel предпочитает именно точку с запятой в качестве разделителя